# Can a function return an array and a variable at the same time,in C?

Tags: c

```
return length;
return user_input;
```

Here length is a value,and user_input is an array.

Comment: You can't even return an array alone.

Comment: The Answer is : **NO**

Comment: But there is one way: You can use **`call by reference`** or `return struct` which is user defined datatype.

Comment: give pointer to the array, return the size. `int f(char** user_input)` now in the function use `*user_input = (char*)malloc(size);` fill it with values and return the size.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To the best of my knowledge, in C you can only return a single value. You can't even return an array, you return a pointer to the array. So unless you want to create a separate struct with an array pointer and an integer specifically for passing things around and returning. There is no way to do this.

Here's how you can do the combined return struct, but usually it's not advised.

```
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<stdio.h>

typedef struct r{
    int *array;
    int val;
}R;

R* my_function();

int main(){
    printf("%d\n",my_function()->val);
}
R* my_function(){

    R* ret_val;
    ret_val = (R*)malloc(1*sizeof(R));
    ret_val->val = 5;
    // Assign your values to the ret_val struct.
    return ret_val;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

No.

Either you'll need to parse pointers in as arguments, or (presuming the returned data is related in some way) define a `struct` that contains the data items and return that.

Answer (score 0):

Nope

But you can pass you array to the function and that way you don't have to return it  and you can just simply return the variable from the function

Here is how:

```
int function(char array[]){
      int length=0;;
      // do whatever you want to do to the array and length
      return length;
}

int main(){
    int functionReturn=0;
    char user_input[50]; // or whatever your array is called

    functionReturn = function(user_input); // this will modify the user_input array without it being returned from the function
                                           // and you will get to return the length value from function
    return 0;
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
struct RET {
 size_t length;
 char user_input[42];
};

struct RET foo()
{
   struct ret = { 0, '0' };
   return ret;
}
```

Comment: I think you mean: `struct ret = { 0, "0" };`

Answer (score 0):

No it can't.
But you can return a pointer to either an array or a single variable.

Answer (score 0):

This can be possible
But using pointers. And a function in C can not return different datatypes.

You can pass place holder for some array/number and return the other one.

```
int func(struct *user_input)
```

Let me know in case you have any further query!!!